# finding maximum sum of a disjoint sequence of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**Problem from :
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/epiccode/challenges/white-falcon-and-sequence.
Visit link for references.**

I have a sequence of integers (-10^6 to 10^6) A. I need to choose two contiguous disjoint subsequences of A, let's say x and y, of the same size, n.

After that you will calculate the sum given by `∑x(i)y(n−i+1)` (1-indexed)

And I have to choose x and y such that sum is maximised.

```
Eg: 
Input: 
12
1 7 4 0 9 4 0 1 8 8 2 4 

Output: 120

Where x = {4,0,9,4}
y = {8,8,2,4}

∑x(i)y(n−i+1)=4×4+0×2+9×8+4×8=120
```

Now, the approach that I was thinking of for this is something in lines of O(n^2) which is as follows:

1. Initialise two variables `l = 0` and `r = N-1`. Here, `N` is the size of the array.
2. Now, for `l=0`, I will calculate the sum while `(l<r)` which basically refers to the subsequences that will start from the 0th position in the array. Then, I will increment `l` and decrement `r` in order to come up with subsequences that start from the above position + 1 and on the right hand side, start from `right-1`.

Is there any better approach that I can use? Anything more efficient? I thought of sorting but we cannot sort numbers since that will change the order of the numbers.

Comment: Are the numbers always non-negative?

Comment: No, the numbers can be negative too.

Comment: I don't understand how your O(n^2) approach is correct. How can you be sure that if x starts at position i, there is an optimal y that starts at n-i-1?

Comment: @NiklasB, you are right. I didn't think of this. My bad. My approach is wrong.

Comment: stop posting programming competition questions.

Comment: The contest has already ended long back, and if I have a doubt, I don't see any harm in posting them here. After all, this is a open discussion forum.

Comment: @JohnLui Can you link to the original problem statement? It might have more information than what you wrote in your question. I find it hard to believe that there is an o(n^2) solution (that is a little-o, not big-o).

Comment: @NiklasB, I have posted the link, and, if you observe carefully, I have written O(n^2) (Big-Oh) notation only, and not little-o.

Comment: @JohnLui I know, and I used little-o in my comment: I don't think there is something *better* than the Omega(n^2) DP solution presented below. The input constraints of N <= 3000 somewhat confirms that at least the authors of the problems aimed for a quadratic solution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question we first define S(i, j) to be the max sum of multlying the two sub-sequence items,  for sub-array A[i...j] when the sub-sequence x starts at position i, and sub-sequence y ends on position j.

For example, if A=[1 7 4 0 9 4 0 1 8 8 2 4], then S(1, 2)=1*7=7 and S(2, 5)=7*9+4*0=63.

The recursive rule to compute S is: S(i, j)=max(0, S(i+1, j-1)+A[i]*A[j]), and the end condition is S(i, j)=0 iff i>=j.

The requested final answer is simply the maximum value of S(i, j) for all combinations of i=1..N, j=1..N, since one of the S(i ,j) values will correspond to the max x,y sub-sequences, and thus will be equal the maximum value for the whole array. The complexity of computing all such S(i, j) values is O(N^2) using dynamic programming, since in the course of computing S(i, j) we will also compute the values of up to N other S(i', j') values, but ultimately each combination will be computed only once.

```
def max_sum(l):
  def _max_sub_sum(i, j):
    if m[i][j]==None:
      v=0
      if i<j:
        v=max(0, _max_sub_sum(i+1, j-1)+l[i]*l[j])
      m[i][j]=v
    return m[i][j]

  n=len(l)
  m=[[None for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
  v=0
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n):
      v=max(v, _max_sub_sum(i, j))
  return v
```

Comment: To clarify the definition of S(i,j) , here's an example with negative numbers: A[1,2,3,-4,5,6]  S(3,4)=max(0, 3*(-4))=0  S(2,5)=max(0,2*5+S(3,4))=10. That is, S(2,5) is 10 because it uses sub-sequences of one element each x=A[2..2]=[2] and y=A[5..5]=[5], and not more (e.g. x=A[2..3] y=A[4..5]) because that will result in a lower sum. The main point is that the sub-sequences x&y used for computing S(i,j) are always such that x starts at i and y ends in j. Only their length varies such that S(i,j) is maximal.

Comment: The recurrence relation should be S[i,j]=max(A[i]*A[j],S[i+1,j-1]+A[i]*A[j]) if i+2<j, and S[i,j]=A[i]*A[j] if i+1==j or i+2==j, for all 1<=i<j<=N (1-indexed)

Comment: Right, you could present the recursive expression as you did, but it's not different than what I specified. For example, in my formula when j=i+2 S(i,j)=max(0, S(i+1, j-1)+A[i]*A[j])=max(0, S(i+1, i+1)+A[i]*A[j])=max(0, A[i]*A[j]) which is the same as your definition  (except that S(i, j) can never be negative).

Answer (score 0):

WARNING:
This method assumes the numbers are non-negative so this solution does not answer the poster's actual problem now it has been clarified that negative input values are allowed.

### Trick 1

Assuming the numbers are always non-negative, it is always best to make the sequences as wide as possible given the location where they meet.

### Trick 2

We can change the sum into a standard convolution by summing over all values of i.  This produces twice the desired result (as we get both the product of x with y, and y with x), but we can divide by 2 at the end to get the original answer.

### Trick 3

You are now attempting to find the maximum of a convolution of a signal with itself.  There is a standard method for doing this which is to use the fast fourier transform.  Some libraries will have this built in, e.g. in Scipy there is [fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html).

### Python code

Note that you don't allow the central value to be reused (e.g. for a sequance 1,3,2 we can't make x 1,3 and y 3,1) so we need to examine alternate values of the convolved output.

We can now compute the answer in Python via:

```
import scipy.signal
A = [1, 7, 4, 0, 9, 4, 0, 1, 8, 8, 2, 4]
print max(scipy.signal.fftconvolve(A,A)[1::2]) / 2
```